# C++20 import modules with dot notation from main file in Clang

Tags: c++, c++20, c++-modules

In a `C++20` project built with `Clang` (stdlib=libc++), I have the next structure:

*testing_core.cppm*

```
export module testing.core;

export namespace testing {

    class TestSuite {
        public:
            static constexpr const char* var [] = { "Hi, constexpr!" };
    };

    void say_hello();
}
```

clang++ -c --std=c++20 -stdlib=libc++ -fmodules -fimplicit-modules -fbuiltin-module-map -fimplicit-module-maps -Xclang -emit-module-interface --precompile -o ./out/modules/interfaces/testing_core.pcm ./zero/ifc/testing/testing_core.cppm

*testing_core.cpp*

```
module testing.core;

import <iostream>;

namespace testing {
    void say_hello() {
        std::cout << "Hi, from the testing module!" << std::endl;
    }
}
```

clang++ -c --std=c++20 -stdlib=libc++ -fmodules -fimplicit-modules -fbuiltin-module-map -fimplicit-module-maps zero/src/testing_core.cpp -o ./out/modules/implementations/testing_core.o -fmodule-file=./out/modules/interfaces/testing_core.pcm

// Driver code
*main.cpp*

```
import testing.core;
import <iostream>;

using namespace zero;

int main() {
    testing::say_hello();

    // Prints const char* first element memory address
    std::cout << testingTestSuite::var << std::endl;
    // Prints the deferenced value of the const char* constexpr
    std::cout << *testingTestSuite::var << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

clang++ --std=c++20 -stdlib=libc++ -fmodules -fimplicit-modules -fbuiltin-module-map -fimplicit-module-maps -o ./out/zero.exe main.cpp ./out/modules/interfaces/testing_core.pcm ./out/modules/interfaces/zero.pcm ./out/modules/interfaces/testing.pcm ./out/modules/implementations/testing.o ./out/modules/implementations/testing_core.o -fprebuilt-module-path=./out/modules/interfaces

The error:

```
main.cpp:3:8: fatal error: module 'testing.core' not found
import testing.core;
~~~~~~~^~~~~~~
1 error generated.
```

I am not being able of import modules from the main file if they have a dot in its identifier.
I am able to import them without having a dot (import testing), when the module name is `testing`, not `testing.core`.

Also, I am also able to `export import testing.core` from another module interface file (for ex: testing.cppm), but I can only import it on the `main.cpp` file as `testing`. This last ones makes perfect sense to me, but I got trapped thinking in why I can `export import` in a module interface unit a module with dots in its identifier, but I can't on a regular `cpp` source file.

What I am missing with Clang here?

Thanks.

Note: Code it's compiled with `Clang 14.0.4`, under a Manjaro `5.13`.

Comment: "Submodules" are not a thing in C++20. There are just modules; the `.` in a module name has no special meaning.

Comment: @NicolBolas this is probably due to GeeksForGeeks and other sites (still) saying that the `.` in a module name denotes a submodule...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution it's pretty straightforward. In `Clang`, (at least in versions up to 14.0.4), you must explicitly include the `-fmodule-file=<some_interface>` for the module files that includes the dot notation in it's identifier.

So, for the `main.cpp` file build process, it must include `-fmodule-file=./out/modules/interfaces/testing_core.pcm` in the command line arguments.

Note: When an interface or implementation file depends on another module interface unit, you also must include the `-fmodule-file` indicating the dependency, even if the module identifier does not contains any dot in it's `export module module_name`.